# POSTing a CSV from FoxPro to an url

Tags: post, foxpro

I'm looking for a concrete example of how FoxPro can generate a CSV or XML chunk and POST it to an URL?

( this is so my URL -> PHP script can then parse and update MySQL )

Comment: Do you want code from VFP to do the generation AND posting to the URL?  Just to be sure you can run the test from within VFP and not just getting script to parallel write in your PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```
USE MyData
COPY TO MyData.csv TYPE delimited
USE
LOCAL lcMyData
lcMyData = FILETOSTR("MyData.csv")

LOCAL xhr
xhr = CREATEOBJECT("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xhr.Open("POST", "http://www.mydomain.com/posthandler.asp", .f.)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
xhr.send("data=" + lcMyData)

LOCAL lcResultText
lcResultText = xhr.responseText;

? lcResultText
xhr = null
```

This has a dependency on the XMLHTTP object which gets installed with Internet Explorer.

Comment: This doesn't sanitize the data.  You should use some form of URL encoding - just in case - the data contains unwanted characters.  Examples of URL encoding are covered very well on West-Wind's web site http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/shellapi/shellapi.asp

Comment: @John L Veazey - This is a good point. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Another great tool to use to get your FoxPro applications online is West Wind Web Connect. It's not free but it's the best tool to get your FoxPro application online.